# Как вывести в twig функцию substr()?

Tags: php, php7, twig

Я поставил Twig, на чистый PHP, передал туда параметры и возник такой вопрос:

У меня есть такой код (выводит текст):

```
<p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
```

Как мне разбить этот текст так, чтобы выводило с него 20 символов и была надпись: *"показать полный текст"*?
К примеру в PHP, это можно сделать через функцию `substr()`.

Но мне нужно именно в Twig это сделать, ибо в самом PHP не прокатит, так как в Twig разбиваю на foreach, и будет сложно.

Comment: Вот пример с документации, возможно это вам поможет https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html

Comment: Не подскажите, то не особо пойму, как это использовать slice(comment.text,20); Что-то не катит, а в самом for смешивать не вариант

Comment: Все нашел решение, спасибо. 
<p>{{ comment.text | slice(0,20) }}</p>
Blade все же попроще чем twig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обрезать тексты через `substr()` нельзя, потому что там могут быть символы состоящие из нескольких байт, а `substr()` обрезает "побайтно". Для *Twig* шаблонов, как уже было сказано в соседнем ответе, есть фильтр `slice`, но и он не очень хорош, поскольку "режет" слова. Лучше обрезать так, чтобы оставались целые слова.

В `Twig` поможет [расширение](http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text.html#truncating-text). Использовать так `{{ comment.text|truncate(20, true) }}` Нужно учитывать, что данная функция обрезает по пробелу **после** достижения длины ограничения (то есть строка будет все-таки немного длинее)

Дополнительно можно передать контент, который будет выведен после обрезки (если она была). По-умолчанию это три точки. Не уверен что можно вставить html-тег (скорее всего нужно будет отключить автоэкранирование и экранировать текст перед обрезкой вручную (фильтром `escape` или `e`). Как-то так

```
{{ comment.text|e|truncate(20, true, '... <a href="#" class="js-more">показать полный текст</a>')|raw }}
```

Как вариант, можно написать свой фильтр, который будет обрезать так как вы хотите.

См. также:

- [Truncate text in Twig & Symfony 2](http://blog.christian-baer.com/index.php/truncate-text-in-twig-symfony-2/) (по-английски) - установка и использование расширения

Comment: У меня пишет, что нет такого фильтра. 
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "truncate" filter.
Не подскажете в чем проблема? То беру и другие примеры с инета, не пашет. Мб версия twig не та

Comment: @nikitaAbramov Расширение нужно установить. См. [документацию](http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)